# Including multi-word stopwords in Solr

Tags: solr, stop-words

Is it possible to include multi-word stopwords in stopfilterfactory of **Solr**? If yes, kindly tell me the way.

Right now first I am putting all the multiple-word stopwords in **synonyms.txt** file and then using one synonym for all these words in **stopwords.txt**, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give a try this kind of a syntax

**stopwords.txt**

```
stop word
more long stop word
```

and it looks like it working. Check out my test case here - https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene5/src/main/scala/org/mystic/SynonymsAndStopwords.scala