# multi word stopwords in solr

Tags: solr, stop-words, phrase

How can I use phrases in stopwords.txt file like 'process for making','method for preparation'. I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667629/including-multi-word-stopwords-in-solr),but could not succeed.Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 3):

How stopwords are used in your environment depends on your configuration. (solr.xml)

For example: if you tokenized the word before applying stopwords, so:
`process for making` will tokenized to `process` `for` `making` and
that will not match your `stopwords.txt` entry, which is `process for making`

Comment: Thanks for your response.Yes I have tokenized the data using standard tokenizer and applying stopfilter factory after it.May be that's why it is not working.What should I do in order to make this work ?

Comment: Go to your Solr Admin page and open the analysis pannel: http://<yourhost>:8080/solr/#/<yourcore>/analysis there you can see, how solr process your input. Probably you have to apply the stopword-filter before tokenizeing by cahngeing the solr.xml